# The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method is greater than authorized

Tags: java, cyclomatic-complexity

I am using below method for checking null or empty field:

```
public boolean isVoNotNull(){
        return null != this.cardNo &&  StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.cardNo) 
                && null != this.otp && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.otp) 
                && null != this.password && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.password)
                && null != this.userid && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.userid) 
                && null != this.type && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.type) 
                && null != this.walletMobileNo && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.walletMobileNo);
    }
```

But getting below exception while this code is validating with SonarLint

> EXCEPTION : The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method "isVoNotNull" is
>   12 which is greater than 10 authorized.

How can I solve this exception or how can I remove the complexity from the code?

Comment: If you're using `StringUtils` from Apache, then why do you check for `null` there?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to analyze duplicated code and refactor it into a reusable method.

Given your original snippet,

```
public boolean isVoNotNull() {
    return null != this.cardNo &&  StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.cardNo) 
        && null != this.otp && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.otp) 
        && null != this.password && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.password)
        && null != this.userid && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.userid) 
        && null != this.type && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.type) 
        && null != this.walletMobileNo && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.walletMobileNo);
}
```

we can identify the following repetitive part:

```
null != this.xxx && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.xxx)
```

Given that `StringUtils#isNotBlank()` [already](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)) checks for `null`, we can further simplify it.

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.xxx)
```

Given that you need to invoke this a variable number of times, best would be to refactor it to a method taking a [variable number of arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) which checks them all in a loop.

```
public static boolean isNoneBlank(String... strings) {
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (!StringUtils.isNotBlank(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or if you're already on Java 8 with [Streams and Lambda](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) support:

```
public static boolean isNoneBlank(String... strings) {
    return Arrays.stream(strings).allMatch(StringUtils::isNotBlank);
}
```

Now you can make use of it as below:

```
public boolean isVoNotNull() {
    return isNoneBlank(this.cardNo, this.otp, this.password, this.userid, this.type, this.walletMobileNo);
}
```

You could further reduce the boilerplate by removing the unnecessary `this`.

```
public boolean isVoNotNull() {
    return isNoneBlank(cardNo, otp, password, userid, type, walletMobileNo);
}
```

This all was an appliance of the [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) software engineering principle.

That said, as [msandiford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047826) pointed out, it turns out that Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils` has since version 3.2 [already](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNoneBlank(java.lang.CharSequence...)) exactly this method. So if you don't have it yet, consider upgrading Apache Commons Lang to at least 3.2.

```
public boolean isVoNotNull() {
    return StringUtils.isNoneBlank(cardNo, otp, password, userid, type, walletMobileNo);
}
```

Comment: Best answer for me, it shows the refactoring process wich is much more valuable than the final correct code snippet

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out the `null` check is redundant as `isNotBlank` checks this too.

So, if you are using Apache StringUtils 3.2 or later, you can just use [StringUtils.isNoneBlank(...)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNoneBlank(java.lang.CharSequence...))

```
public boolean isVoNotNull() {
    return StringUtils.isNoneBlank(cardNo, otp, password, userid, type, walletMobileNo);
}
```

If you are using an earlier version, you could easily write one:

```
public static boolean isNoneBlank(CharSequence... seqs) {
  for (CharSequence seq : seqs) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(seq))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or in Java 8:

```
public static boolean isNoneBlank(CharSequence... seqs) {
  return Stream.of(seqs).allMatch(StringUtils::isNotBlank);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the strings to an array and check with a loop for nullity and not blank-ness. Worst performance of course but should break that non-sensed limit.

Example code:

```
public boolean isVoNotNull(){
    string [] stringsToCheck = new string[]{
    this.cardNo,
    this.otp,
    // ...
    }

    //return CheckStringArrayNotNull(stringsToCheck);        
    return StringUtils.isNoneBlank(stringsToCheck);
}

// high chance this method already exists inside StringUtils
// INFACT FOUND! :)
private boolean CheckStringArrayNotNull( string [] stringsToCheck){
     for(int i=0; i<stringsToCheck.length(); i++)
        if( StringUtils.isNotBlank( stringsToCheck[i]) == false)
            return false;

    return true; 
}
```

or even better, (EDIT: seems @msandiford beat me on time for this solution)

```
public boolean isVoNotNull(){      
    return StringUtils.isNoneBlank(cardNo, otp, ...);
}
```

You could of course break into more methods to reduce cyclomatic complexity but that makes the class even harder to read and understand. Code metrics should be used only to investigate problems, not as a development mantra, for example I can take a very stupid class with 100 methods each with Cyclomatic complexity of 100 and refactor it so that it has perfect code metrics but is impossible to understand. Never look at code metrics, think to good solutions without using coding metrics.

Answer (score 0):

StringUtils.isNotBlank

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

"Checks if a CharSequence is not empty (""), not null and not whitespace only."

The function already check if the object is null, then you can simplify

```
public boolean isVoNotNull() { 
  return StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.cardNo) 
      && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.otp) 
      && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.password)
      && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.userid) 
      && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.type) 
      && StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.walletMobileNo);
}
```

To reduce the number of conditional operators, you can do something like this:

```
public boolean isVoNotNull(){
  Boolean[] condition = new Boolean[] {
      StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.cardNo), 
      StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.otp),
      StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.password),
      StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.userid), 
      StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.type),
      StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.walletMobileNo)
  };
  return BooleanUtils.and(condition);
}
```

Maybe is a little tricky, but it work